# Embedding Google Calendar Containing Imported Calendars that are not Public

Tags: iframe, calendar, google-calendar-api

I am trying embed three calendars (Homeaway, Trip Advisor and Airbnb) onto my website, however none of the three have explicit widget functionality to enable them to be embed.

All three do however allow you to add the calendar's to your own google calendar, so I figured the best way around this would be to add them to google calendar then embed the google calendar onto my website.

I have set the permission settings to 'Anyone can' see all event details after importing these into google calendar.

Upon exporting and adding the iframe to the website, the event calendar produces the following error which I believe is due to the calendars I've imported not being enabled to publically be shared from the source they have been imported: [Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OUhZ9.png)

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to get around this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discussed this with a representative from Homeaway and Trip Advisor if anyone was looking for an answer to this same issue.

They have permissions for their calendars set so that this is not possible. Unfortunately linking to their website for the calendar seems to be the best way to do this.